# Textview overlapping on LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a RecyclerView and that code is the item layout for the recycler.

It's a text message and the time on the right.

If the text is small it works ok. 
[image]
But when the text is large the time TextView is not shown
[image]

I can set maxWidth but I dont want to do it like that. I want to know how to fix the time always in the layout

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_message"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="left">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
        android:text="Hello Mike bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla "
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_msg_time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:text="10:20"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

**EDIT**:
First answer comment:
[image]
I want to wrap the content is the text is small

**EDIT**:
The solution that works for me is only using android:maxWidth

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_message"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="left">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxWidth="320dp"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
        android:text="la lalala la lalala la lalala la lalala la lalala la lalala la lalala la lalala la lalala la lalala la lalala la lalala la lalala la lalala la lalala la lalala @string/prompt_message"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_msg_time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:text="10:20"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"

        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Put weight on tv_message textview

Answer (score 4):

**Try this** : Add **weight** to your message textview.

[image]

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_message"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="left">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
        android:text="Hello Mike bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla "
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_msg_time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:text="10:20"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:gravity="bottom"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It doen't work whe the text is short. The text view of the time takes all the screen, and the text is shown on the left border

Comment: can you add the link of that screen shot in comment ? so i can better understand the problem

Comment: Added EDIT: with the screen shot

Comment: It works for me. However, is it tested on various android versions?

Comment: Hi @PawanSingh Yes it will work in different size devices as well. you can try from device settings can change display size and verify.

Comment: Thank you , I came across this exact issue , your solution is perfect.

Answer (score 2):

Use this layout instead.This will solve your problem.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout_message"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_message"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingRight="30dp"
        android:text="Hello Mike bla bla bla  bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla " />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_msg_time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tv_message"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="10:20"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="10sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your layout a bit like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_message"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:gravity="start">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_message"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".85"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
        android:text="Hello Mike bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla "
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_msg_time"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".15"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:text="10:20"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Added EDIT: , your code works in the same way as the EDIT screen shot

Comment: and what do you want ??

Comment: the first screen shot also for large texts

Answer (score 0):

As said by @AbhayBohra, use the weight property on the textviews and set the width as 0dp, like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_message"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="left">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_message"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="7"
    style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
    android:text="Hello Mike bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla "
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_msg_time"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="2"

    android:textSize="10sp"
    android:text="10:20"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Added EDIT: , your code works in the same way as the EDIT screen shot